# Aggregate as part of ETL or within the database?

Tags: postgresql, database-design, etl

Is there a general preference or best practice when it comes whether the data should be aggregated in memory on an ETL worker (with pandas groupby or pd.pivot_table, for example), versus doing a groupby query at the database level?

At the visualization layer, I connect to the last 30 days of detailed interaction-level data, and then the last few years of aggregated data (daily level).

I suppose that if I plan on materializing the aggregated table, it would be best to just do it during the ETL phase since that can be done remotely and not waste the resources of the database server. Is that correct?

Answer (score 1):

If your concern is to put as little load on the source database server as possible, it is best to pull the tables from the source database to a staging area and do joins and aggregations there. But take care that the ETL tool does *not* perform a nested loop join on the source database tables, that is to pull in one of the tables and then run thousands of queries against the other table to find matching rows.

If your target is to perform joins and aggregations as fast and efficient as possible, by all means push them down to the source database. This may put more load on the source database though. I say “may” because if all you need is an aggregation on a single table, it can be cheaper to perform this in the source database than to pull the whole table.

Answer (score 1):

If you aggregate by day, what if you boss wants it aggregated by hour or week?

The general rule is: Your fact table granularity should be as granular as possible. Then you can drill-down.

You can create pre-aggregated tables too, for example by hour, day, week, month, etc. Space is cheap these days.

Tools like [Pentaho Aggregation Designer](https://help.pentaho.com/Documentation/6.1/0N0/010/010) can automate this for you.

Comment: Oh, for sure I am keeping the granular data as separate tables. My coworker prefers to create materialized views. However, if we are dealing with a couple of years of data, it takes quite a while compared to 'incremental' aggregation every day during the ETL phase.